# Boot physical win10 disk in QEMU

Tags: windows, boot, virtual-machine, bios, qemu

https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/179771-using-physical-disk-kvm-qemu-windows-vm.html?__cf_chl_tk=z_c4bUjts37uHd66EhURNiy75Wla6ioAk1ettZofip4-1670079604-0-gaNycGzNCH0
this got me the farthest but i am stuck at qemu's bios displaying: Booting from Hard Disk...

i have tried setting uefi in virt-manager setting but windows bluescreens with: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DISK(or something like that i dont remember what it actually was)

how to boot windows? or is there another way to run a windows vm and access all of its files in linux host?

Comment: From Linux:    smb://192.168.x.y/folder  .  That is SMB with the IP address of the Windows Guest.  I do this routinely.

Comment: @John yes, but i want to access them at any time and not only when windows is running. dual booting is also not an option

Comment: In any traditional VM app,  a disk has to be migrated to boot as a virtual device. So I am not sure if what you are trying to do is entirely practical

Comment: One option for you is to organize your document store and then copy it to a USB drive and keep it in sync.  That will be available any time.

Comment: i need to access all of windows's files, not just share some folder with it.

Comment: You are making this vastly too complicated. Run the Windows machine. Done

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a standard image file and mount it onto your host (which I assume is Linux) FS.

Try this method to mount a qcow2 image - https://gist.github.com/shamil/62935d9b456a6f9877b5

Please mind that you should not do that while the VM is running. If you need access to the VM files while the VM is running, the only safe way of doing that is by sharing the boot drive from within Windows and mounting it using Samba of cifs driver.